# Falha ao realizar insert SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, tabela-html

Ao executar esse trecho de código, retorna o erro abaixo. Qual pode ser a causa?

```
public class LivroDaVendaDAO {

    // sqlite
    private ConexaoSQLite sqliteDataBase;

    // nome da tabela de livrosDaVenda
    private final String TBL_LIVRO_DA_VENDA = "tbl_livros_da_venda";

    // nome das colunas da tabela livrosDaVenda
    private final String KEY_CODIGO = "pk_lv_ve_codigo";
    private final String KEY_LIV_CODIGO = "liv_codigo";
    private final String KEY_VEN_CODIGO = "ven_codigo";
    private final String KEY_QUANTIDADE = "lv_ve_quantidade";

    // colunas da tabela
    private final String[] COLUNAS = { KEY_CODIGO, KEY_LIV_CODIGO, KEY_VEN_CODIGO, KEY_QUANTIDADE };

    public LivroDaVendaDAO(ConexaoSQLite pSqliteDataBase) {
        this.sqliteDataBase = pSqliteDataBase;
    }

    /**
     * Salva um livroDaVenda no banco
     * 
     * @param livroDaVenda
     * @return long - codigo do ultimo livroDaVenda inserido
     */
    public long salvarLivroDaVendaDAO(LivroDaVenda livroDaVenda) {
        long lvVeCodigo = 0; // codigo do ultimo livroDaVenda inserido

        // recupera a instancia do banco para efetuar escrita
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.sqliteDataBase.getWritableDatabase();

        try {

            // Cria os contentValues (nomes das colunas das tabelas e
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            // valores que ser�o inseridos no banco de dados)
            values.put(KEY_LIV_CODIGO, livroDaVenda.getLvVeLivro().getLivCodigo());
            values.put(KEY_VEN_CODIGO, livroDaVenda.getVenCodigo());
            values.put(KEY_QUANTIDADE, livroDaVenda.getLvVeQuantidade());

            // executa o insert no banco
            lvVeCodigo = db.insert(TBL_LIVRO_DA_VENDA, // nome da tabela
                    null, // nullColumnHack
                    values); // key/valores

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("DB_ERROR", "NÃO FOI POSSÍVEL INSERIR O LIVRO DA VENDA");
        } finally {
            // fecha a conexao
            db.close();
        }
        return lvVeCodigo;
    }

    /**
     * Retorna um livroDaVenda da base de dados
     * 
     * @param pLivCodigo
     * @return Livro
     */
    public LivroDaVenda getLivroDaVendaDAO(long pLivCodigo) {

        // novo livroDaVenda vazio
        LivroDaVenda livroDaVenda = new LivroDaVenda();

        // recupera a instancia do banco para efetuar apenas leituras
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.sqliteDataBase.getReadableDatabase();

        // cursor para movimentar entre os resultados da query
        Cursor cursor = null;

        try {

            // constroi a consulta (query)
            // veja outro modo de consulta no metodo getListaLivroDAO
            cursor = db.query(TBL_LIVRO_DA_VENDA, // a. tabela
                    COLUNAS, // b. nomes das colunas
                    KEY_CODIGO + " = ?", // c. selections (where)
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(pLivCodigo) }, // d.
                    // selections
                    // args
                    null, // e. group by
                    null, // f. having
                    null, // g. order by
                    null); // h. limit

            // vai para o primeiro resultado, caso exista
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
            }

            // cria um livroDaVenda com os dados vindos do banco
            // livroDaVenda.setLivCodigo(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            // livroDaVenda.setLivNome(cursor.getString(1));
            // livroDaVenda.setLivValor(cursor.getFloat(2));
            // livroDaVenda.setDisCodigo(cursor.getInt(3));
            // livroDaVenda.setLivEstoque(cursor.getInt(4));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("DB_ERROR", "NÃO FOI POSSÍVEL RECUPERAR O LIVRO");
        } finally {
            // fecho o cursor
            cursor.close();
            // fecho a conexao
            db.close();
        }

        // retorna o livroDaVenda
        return livroDaVenda;
    }

    /**
     * Recupero uma lista contendo todos os livrosDaVenda do banco
     * 
     * @return List - lista de livrosDaVenda
     */
    public ArrayList<LivroDaVenda> getListaLivroDaVendaDAO() {
        Livro livroDaVenda = null;
        ArrayList<LivroDaVenda> listaLivro = new ArrayList<LivroDaVenda>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;

        // constroi a query
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TBL_LIVRO_DA_VENDA + " ORDER BY " + KEY_LIV_CODIGO;

        try {
            // recupero a referencia a leitura no banco
            db = this.sqliteDataBase.getReadableDatabase();

            // crio um cursor (busca resultados na consulta)
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

            // movo cursor para primeiro registro
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                // recupero cada livroDaVenda com os dados vindos do banco
                do {
                    livroDaVenda = new Livro();
                    livroDaVenda.setLivCodigo(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(0)));
                    livroDaVenda.setLivNome(cursor.getString(1));
                    livroDaVenda.setLivValor(cursor.getFloat(2));
                    livroDaVenda.setDisCodigo(cursor.getLong(3));
                    livroDaVenda.setLivEstoque(cursor.getInt(4));

                    // adiciono cada livroDaVenda encontrado a uma lista
                    // listaLivro.add(livroDaVenda);

                    // movo cursor para proximo registro
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("DB_ERROR", "NÃO FOI POSSÍVEL LISTAR LIVRO_DA_VENDA");
        } finally {
            // fecho o cursor
            cursor.close();
            // fecho a conexao
            db.close();
        }

        return listaLivro;
    }

    /**
     * Exclui os livrosDaVenda de uma venda da base de dados
     * 
     * @param pVenCodigo
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean excluirLivrosDaVendaDAO(long pVenCodigo) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try {
            // recupera uma instancia de escrita no banco
            db = this.sqliteDataBase.getWritableDatabase();

            // executa o delete no banco
            db.delete(
            // tabela
                    TBL_LIVRO_DA_VENDA,
                    // selection (where)
                    KEY_VEN_CODIGO + " = ?",
                    // valores do selection
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(pVenCodigo) });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("DB_ERROR", "NÃO FOI POSSÍVEL DELETAR O LIVRO");
            return false;
        } finally {
            // fecha a conexão
            db.close();
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Erro:

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: tbl_livros_da_venda E/SQLiteDatabase:
>   Error inserting ven_codigo=11 liv_codigo=0 lv_ve_quantidade=1
>                     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tbl_livros_da_venda (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO
>   tbl_livros_da_venda(ven_codigo,liv_codigo,lv_ve_quantidade) VALUES
>   (?,?,?)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1472)
>                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1343)
>                         at com.br.DAO.LivroDaVendaDAO.salvarLivroDaVendaDAO(LivroDaVendaDAO.java:58)
>                         at com.br.controller.LivroDaVendaCtrl.salvarLivroDaVendaCtrl(LivroDaVendaCtrl.java:35)
>                         at com.br.activity.VendaActivity$2$1.onClick(VendaActivity.java:321)
>                         at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: Faltou o `create table` para criar a tabela `tbl_livros_da_venda `

Comment: Isac o Create Table está criada dbHelper

String sqlTabelaLivroVenda =
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_livros_da_venda" +
      "(" +
      //codigo do livro da venda
      "pk_lv_ve_codigo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
      //referencia para livro
      "liv_codigo INTEGER, " +
      //referencia para venda 
      "ven_codigo INTEGER," +
      //quantidade do item vendido
      "lv_ve_quantidade INTEGER" +
      "); ";

e está sendo chamada.

Comment: Yuri, isso acontece pq vc adicionou alguma coluna a tabela, depois dela ter sido criada e instalada na memória interna do seu device, desinstala o app e roda de novo, que vai resolver, ou você pode aumentar a versão do banco tbm, mudando pra 2 (caso esteja na versão 1) vai resolver também

Comment: Não vejo isso que indicou no código da pergunta. Mas se tem a criação pode ser também o que o @LeonardoDias indicou, porque as alterações ao banco de dados implicam reinstalar a aplicação ou mudar versão do banco de dados. Mas o erro é claro "(...) no such table (...)" ou seja não encontrou a tabela `tbl_livros_da_venda`.

Comment: Foi o que imaginei tbm quando li Isac. Obrigado irei ver direitinho
Vou ver o que o Leonardo indicou também

Comment: Arrumei com a atualização da Versão como o Leonardo disse, Obrigado.